# combine n dicts in one list of dicts

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine n tables (lists that contains dicts) if the common keys have the same values .therefore i'm using *arg and another two tables .my code worked okay with two tables but for some unknown reason *args return nothing .
My CODE :

```
def join(tbl1, tbl2, *args):
    _dic = {}
    _list = []
    dictsOutOfArgs = []
    for d in args:
        dictsOutOfArgs.append(d)
    for t1, t2 , arg in zip(tbl1, tbl2, dictsOutOfArgs):
        for i , j , z in zip(t1, t2, arg):
            if i == j == z and t1.get(i) == t2.get(j) == arg.get(z):
                _dic = t1.copy()
                _dic.update(t2)
                _dic.update(arg)
                _list.append(_dic)

    return _list

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import pprint
  print(test_answer())
  print(test_answer1())
  series = [
  {'s_id': 'bb', 'title': 'Breaking Bad'},
  {'s_id': 'bcs', 'title': 'Better Call Saul'}]
  characters = [
  {'c_id': 'ww', 'family_name': 'White', 'given_name': 'Walter'},
  {'c_id': 'sw', 'family_name': 'White', 'given_name': 'Skyler'},
  {'c_id': 'sg', 'family_name': 'Goodman', 'given_name': 'Saul'}]
  series_characters = [
  {'c_id': 'ww', 's_id': 'bb'},
  {'c_id': 'sw', 's_id': 'bb'},
  {'c_id': 'sg', 's_id': 'bb'},
  {'c_id': 'sg', 's_id': 'bcs'}]
  x = join(series_characters, series, characters)

  pprint.pprint(x)
```

expected output :

```
[{'c_id': 'ww',
    'family_name': 'White',
    'given_name': 'Walter',
    's_id': 'bb',
    'title': 'Breaking Bad'},
    {'c_id': 'sw',
    'family_name': 'White',
    'given_name': 'Skyler',
    's_id': 'bb',
    'title': 'Breaking Bad'},
    {'c_id': 'sg',
    'family_name': 'Goodman',
    'given_name': 'Saul',
    's_id': 'bb',
    'title': 'Breaking Bad'},
    {'c_id': 'sg',
    'family_name': 'Goodman',
    'given_name': 'Saul',
    's_id': 'bcs',
    'title': 'Better Call Saul'}]
```

return is : []
and i think the reason is that argss does not have any values , so the if condition return false .

any ideas ?

Comment: From your code, I can not tell what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you explain what you are wanting to happen?  It looks like you are expecting `zip` to perform a natural join?

Comment: @PaulRooney merge n dicts that have the same keys and the same values

Comment: @cmd zip is getting out the dicts from the lists the other for loop gitting  the keys of the dicts the if and what come next what your referred to a "natural join " , i dont know how did you understand that :)

Comment: @PaulRooney i have edited the code and added the expected output

Comment: @james Is `dictsOutOfArgs.append(arg1)` a typo? Where is `arg1` defined? This should throw an error, not return an empty list.

Comment: @brianpck sorry i just changed the variables names forgot about that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this (note its a little picky about order of tables):

```
def join(tbl1, *args):
    ret_list = []
    for obj in tbl1:
        consolidated = obj.copy()
        for join_tbl in args:
            keys = consolidated.viewkeys() & join_tbl[0].viewkeys()
            match_obj = next(o for o in join_tbl if all(consolidated.get(k) == o.get(k) for k in keys))
            if match_obj:
                consolidated.update(match_obj)
        ret_list.append(consolidated)
    return ret_list
```

`join(series_characters, series, characters)` returns

```
{'c_id': 'ww', 'given_name': 'Walter', 'title': 'Breaking Bad', 's_id': 'bb', 'family_name': 'White'}
{'c_id': 'sw', 'given_name': 'Skyler', 'title': 'Breaking Bad', 's_id': 'bb', 'family_name': 'White'}
{'c_id': 'sg', 'given_name': 'Saul', 'title': 'Breaking Bad', 's_id': 'bb', 'family_name': 'Goodman'}
{'c_id': 'sg', 'given_name': 'Saul', 'title': 'Better Call Saul', 's_id': 'bcs', 'family_name': 'Goodman'}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but what if i got tbl1 and tbl2

Comment: It uses the base table you want, as tbl1 all other tables as args.  Basically it does a `left outer natural join` with every other table in order specified.  ie. left outer natural joins series_characters with series, then take that consolidated result and left outer natural joins to characters.  tbl1 is just used as a starting table.

Comment: or are you saying you need to have the function header of `def join(tbl1, tbl2, *args):` for some reason?

Comment: yeah it should be like this , it's not problem i can change the code to suite my needs . Thanks sir !